# Unable to pull dvc data from remote path. Keeps giving "Everything is up to date"

Tags: amazon-s3, dvc

I am trying to pull a csv file which was pushed to dvc via a gh action (The file was created, and pushed via gh action).

I have the `.dvc` version file of the csv in local (I've made gh actions echo the file contents). However, when I am trying to pull the file into local using the same config of remote path, it just says `Everything is up to date`, but I don't fine the csv anywhere in local.

I keep facing the same issue even when I use `--force` after my dvc pull command.

Is there something which I am doing wrong in this setup?

(PS: I do have `dvc-s3` setup, and my repo is a dvc repo too)

Comment: Sounds weird. Could you run `dvc pull -v` and capture the logs. Could you also run `dvc data status`, `dvc dag --outs` on CI? Btw, `local` - what do you mean by local in this case?

Comment: I'd also confirm that your GitHub actions created a new commit with the updated tracking file and that your local git repo is checkout'd to the same commit.